# Objects show as outlines instead of solids

Tags: mesh, objects, properties

[image: workspace]

I've recently installed blender and when I open the software the cube in the workspace is not in solid form. It is shown using lines and, also, when I add a new object it is not filled but it is shown in lines. Then i go to edit mode and do a small change then again the solid form appears. As you can see in the picture below, I tried to add an object and it comes in lines and not in solid form. Then i went to edit mode made a small change in the shape, then I can see a solid object in the object mode. your help will be most appreciated.

[image: this is the screen shot]

Comment: This is a common problem with unsupported graphics hardware (and occasionally out of date drivers). Check here to make sure your GPU is compatible - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Other than replacing the GPU is there anything I can do

Comment: You could try using an older version of blender. 2.79 might work for you.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Hey buddy, thanks i've installed 2.80 and its working just fine..You on instagram?